# Apply background color after window loads completely

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, window

I'm calling the `openLogo` function on a button click. A new window opens and displays the logo. Some of my logos are white in color, so after the window opens I need to change the background color of the window so that the white logo is visible. The background color of the window that is opening is displaying in a different color(light grey) as expected in IE, but in Firefox the background color flashes for a second and disappears. I think the background color is applied even before the page loads fully. Is there a way to apply background color after the new pop up window loads fully so that I could see the background color as light grey in firefox as well?

```
function openLogo(){
    if(document.getElementById("whiteRadio").checked){
        myWindow = window.open(logoMap[version + "-" + where + "-" + size + "-" + color + "-" + symbol]);
        myWindow.document.bgColor="lightgrey";                       
    }
    else {
        myWindow = window.open(logoMap[version + "-" + where + "-" + size + "-" + color + "-" + symbol]);
    }
}
```

Thanks. The updated code is:

```
function openLogo(){
    if(document.getElementById("whiteRadio").checked){
        var logosrc = "https://" + document.location.hostname + logoMap[version + "-" + where + "-" + size + "-" + color + "-" + symbol];
        var w = window.open(logoMap[version + "-" + where + "-" + size + "-" + color + "-" + symbol]);
        w.document.writeln("<body>");
        w.document.writeln("<div style=background-color:#DEDEDE><img src='" + logosrc + "'><\/div>");
        w.document.writeln("<\/body>");
        w.document.close();              
    }
    else {
        myWindow = window.open(logoMap[version + "-" + where + "-" + size + "-" + color + "-" + symbol]);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you FishBasketGordo for styling the code. It looks more readable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some script in the pop-up page itself that sets its own background colour.

Answer (score 0):

```
myWindow.document.body.bgColor="lightgrey";
```